# Can't multithread but works with a for loop or single thread

Tags: c, multithreading, multidimensional-array, pthreads, lightweight-processes

I'm trying to get multiple threads to perform parallel calculations on a 2D array.
The user specifies how many threads they want so on a 25*25 2d array if the user wants 5 threads then each thread performs calculation on 125 elements. (for simplicity I hardcoded these number just to try and get program to work under these conditions).

The code works for 1 thread and when I simulated with a for loop everything works correctly. It's a conways game of life program. With 1 thread or forloop calling gen function 5 times the programs works fine. It prints out the grids properly. With 5 threads it just prints out once and program ends

I can't test inside the threads because printf doesn't work in threads. I've spent hours on this and I can't figure it out.

```
int N; 
int **gridA;// odd generations
int **gridB;//even
int T = 5;//number of threads

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){
  int i,j;
  const int STACK_SIZE = 65536;
  char *stack;
  char *stackTop[t];
  pid_t cret[t], wret;
  N = 25;//array size [25][25];
  //initialize stack
   stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
  for(i = 0; i < T; i++){
    stackTop[i] = stack + STACK_SIZE;
  }

//initilize arrays and load gridA with input

    while(1){}
      for(i=0; i < T; i++) cret[i]=clone(generateNext, stackTop[i], CLONE_VM|SIGCHLD, (void*)i);//thread code
      for(i=0; i < T; i++) waitpid(cret[i],&status,0);//wait for threads to finish       

   //for(i=0; i < T; i++){generateNext((void*)i);} Simulate threads, works like this
    if(toggle){//grids used interchangeably. 
  print_array(gridA);
        toggle = 0;
    } else {
        print_array(gridB);
        toggle = 1;
    }
  }
}

//figures out the next generation
void generateNext(void *p){
//finds out the two points each thread will calculate for by using p
//eg first thread: gridA[0][24] to [4][24] 2nd thread: [5][25] to 9[25]
//then finds neighbours and changes state of each element accordingly

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(1){}` is a bad idea. Please provide the code that actually causes problems.

That said `clone()` and `waitpid()` are not really for multithreading but for multiprocessing. Since processes have separate memory spaces, this can't work. Please check out any pthread tutorial to get you started with multithreading.